# Clarification about Phong lighting model

Tags: lighting

I've read some tutorials about Phong and Blinn lighting models and tried to implement a rendered myself.
To my knowledge, the basic approach consists of the following steps:

- calculate the vector from the current fragment to the light `rayToLight` (and normalize it)
- calculate the diffuse color intensity using `diffuseIntensity = max(dot(rayToLight, normal))`
- calculate the vector from the current fragment and the camera `rayToCamera` (and normalize it)
- reflect `rayToLight`: `reflected = reflect(-rayToLight, normal)`
- calculate the `specularIntensity = pow(max(dot(reflected, rayToCamera), 0.0), shininess)`.

The problem is that `specularIntensity` ( `dot(reflected, rayToCamera)` to be precise), can be non-zero even if the light and the camera are on the opposite sides of a surface. Take the following example
[image]
It is possible that the angle between `reflected` and `rayToCamera` is less than 90 deg even if the camera and the light are on the opposite sides of a surface.
This means that despite the surface is not lit by the diffuse light, it can show specular reflections which is, of course, not wanted.
I wasn't aware of this problem until it occurred when I was trying to implement a simple phong lighting model.

Have I done something wrong or is it just the way it should work?
Thanks

Comment: yes it's necessary to check whether `dot(light_dir, norm)` is positive or not. If negative we don't need to include specular component.

Comment: I see, I wonder why the majority of tutorials don't bring up this caveat. Thank you very much @gallickgunner . Feel free to add your comment as an answer as it is exactly what I was looking for.